# "echo" this special escaped char in bash

Tags: bash, echo, unicode-literals

I am struggling to print out (i.e. echo) the non-ASCII Unicode character ["Latin Capital Letter C with Caron" `U+010C`](https://codepoints.net/U+010C?lang=en).

As can be seen in [my online Python IDE](https://www.online-python.com/YFi9MhpOrj), the code compiles and prints the character successfully. However, I cannot get similar code to work in Bash. So far, I have been using an [online Bash shell](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell).

How can I get this to run in Bash?

Comment: Which encoding do you want to use? If it’s UTF-8 then `printf '\304\214\n'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -e flag which enables the interpretation of escaped characters.

```bash
echo -e 'https://codepoints.net/\u010C?lang=en'
```